# JWPlayer page refresh error: Could not load plugins:File not found

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jwplayer

i am using JWPlayer in Localhost

and here is my code:

```
<div id="Player">loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("Player").setup({
    file: "<?php echo $video['path']; ?>",
    //image: "/test.jpg",
    displaytitle: false,
    author: "Mohammad Masoudian",
    autoStart: false,
    volume: 75,
    width: 544,
    height: 400
});
</script>
```

when i go to this address **http://cms2.localhost.com/video/1/** i can see the video but when i refresh the page i receive this error?

**Could not load plugins:File not found**

why?

Comment: sounds to me like your php script isn't loading $video['path'] when you refresh the page

Comment: i check it in other browsers and i think its browser problem

Comment: Can you put up a public url displaying the problem?

Comment: this isn't code problem or JWPlayer problem i think this was firefox problem. when i restarted the browser the problem solved

Comment: Ah great, glad you got it!

Comment: Hi there - you should answer your own question and mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't code problem or JWPlayer problem i think this was firefox problem. when i restarted the browser the problem solved

Answer (score 2):

jwplayer is kind of a spyware that will refuse to run with the said error message if it can not connect to jwpcdn.com.

Well 'spyware' may be a bit hyperbole, but it does send statistics home.

A corporate guy from longplayer confirms this here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/29508/jw6-phones-home-privacy-concerns/

allegedly this behaviour can be disabled in the non-free version.